# Why does this fizz buzz code in Rust slower than Node.js?

Tags: node.js, performance, rust

I wrote a Rust function that accepts n and returns the fizz buzz sequence from 1 to n. Then I wrote the equivalent in JavaScript and did some benchmarks. Node.js was quite faster than Rust. I did compile and run Rust in release mode with `cargo run -r`.

For n=100, repetitions=1e6:
Node.js: 707ms
Rust: 1047ms

For n=1000, repetitions=1e6:
Node.js: 6.7s
Rust: 11s

How can I rewrite the Rust code so that it's faster? And how did Node (or v8) optimize the code for it to run so fast?

Below's the code.

JavaScript

```
const fizzBuzz = n => {
  let res = '1'

  for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    res += ' '

    if (i % 15 === 0) {
      res += 'fizzbuzz'
    } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
      res += 'fizz'
    } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
      res += 'buzz'
    } else {
      res += i
    }
  }

  return res
}

const perf = (f, n) => {
  console.time()

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    f()
  }

  console.timeEnd()
}

perf(() => fizzBuzz(100), 1e6)
perf(() => fizzBuzz(1000), 1e6)
// default: 707.632ms
// default: 6.683s
```

Rust

```
fn calc_capacity(n: f32) -> f32 {
    n // spaces
        + (n / 30.0 * 12.0) * 4.0 // fizz buzz
        + (n / 30.0 * 2.0) * 8.0 // fizzbuzz
        + (n / 30.0 * 16.0) * f32::log10(n).ceil() // numbers
}

pub fn fizz_buzz(n: u32) -> String {
    let mut res = String::with_capacity(calc_capacity(n as f32) as usize);
    res.push('1');
    for i in 2..n {
        res.push(' ');
        if i % 15 == 0 {
            res.push_str("fizzbuzz");
        } else if i % 3 == 0 {
            res.push_str("fizz");
        } else if i % 5 == 0 {
            res.push_str("buzz");
        } else {
            res.push_str(&i.to_string());
        }
    }
    res
}

pub fn perf(f: &dyn Fn(), n: u32) {
    let start_time = Instant::now();

    for _ in 0..n {
        f();
    }

    let end_time = Instant::now();

    println!("{}ms", end_time.duration_since(start_time).as_millis());
}

perf(
    &|| {
        fizz_buzz(100);
    },
    1e6 as u32,
);
perf(
    &|| {
        fizz_buzz(1000);
    },
    1e6 as u32,
);
// 1047ms
// 10927ms
```

I tried to optimize the Rust code by calculating the result string's capacity in advance to prevent reallocations and tried using the string's vec directly but the result was quite the same.

```
const FIZZ: &[u8; 4] = &[102, 105, 122, 122];
const BUZZ: &[u8; 4] = &[98, 117, 122, 122];

pub fn fizz_buzz_2(n: u32) -> String {
    let mut res = String::with_capacity(calc_capacity(n as f32) as usize);
    let vec = unsafe { res.as_mut_vec() };
    vec.push(b'1');
    for i in 2..n {
        vec.push(b' ');
        if i % 15 == 0 {
            vec.extend_from_slice(FIZZ);
            vec.extend_from_slice(BUZZ);
        } else if i % 3 == 0 {
            vec.extend_from_slice(FIZZ);
        } else if i % 5 == 0 {
            vec.extend_from_slice(BUZZ);
        } else {
            vec.extend_from_slice(i.to_string().as_bytes());
        }
    }
    res
}
```

Comment: Did you compile the Rust code with `--release`?

Comment: I sure did. cargo run -r

Comment: Also note that you are timing your execution *within* the program you wrote, which completely neglects the startup time of the node.js runtime. Use the unix `time` utility or something like it to time your program execution. Also make sure when you do that you are directly running your rust build artifact and not using cargo.

Comment: As per Rust docs, Instant is suitable for measuring benchmarks. In both Rust and JavaScript code, I only time the duration of the test.

Comment: "the result was quite the same" which is obvious if you analyze the core problem: you're allocating a string on every iteration in the last clause. Whether you then append its content to a slice or a string doesn't really make a difference, in rust allocations are expensive.

Comment: The slow part of the rust code is the `i.to_string()` part, if you e.g. use `itoa` to convert the string then the rust code is faster then the JavaScript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript has one big advantage here: it has a garbage collector. In this code we allocate a lot of small objects and free them (for the number's strings). In V8 allocation is just a pointer bump, and deallocation is done en mass; in Rust we use a full allocator.

Fortunately, Rust is more low-level than JS, and we can avoid creating garbage at all by using a stack allocated array:

```rust
pub fn v2(n: u32) -> String {
    let mut numbers_buffer = [0; 20];
    let mut res = Vec::with_capacity(calc_capacity(n as f32) as usize);
    res.push(b'1');
    for mut i in 2..n {
        res.push(b' ');
        if i % 15 == 0 {
            res.extend_from_slice(b"fizzbuzz");
        } else if i % 3 == 0 {
            res.extend_from_slice(b"fizz");
        } else if i % 5 == 0 {
            res.extend_from_slice(b"buzz");
        } else {
            let mut current_buffer_position = 19;
            loop {
                numbers_buffer[current_buffer_position] = (i % 10) as u8 + b'0';
                i /= 10;
                if i == 0 {
                    break;
                }
                current_buffer_position -= 1;
            }

            res.extend_from_slice(&numbers_buffer[current_buffer_position..]);
        }
    }
    String::from_utf8(res).unwrap()
}
```

Without unsafe at all, this code runs at 295ms and 2.851s on my machine, whereas your Rust code runs at 1.669s and 17.165s, and your JS code runs at 642ms and 5.926s.

I believe V8 has another trick in its sleeves here: it doesn't really allocates and copies the string to grow it here, it just represents it in memory as tree of concatenated strings. This isn't enough to defeat our optimized Rust, though, even though it doesn't do that.

Comment: For what it's worth you can get most of the way there by just replacing `res.push_str(&i.to_string());` by `write!(&mut res, "{}", i)` in the original code, on my machine for fizzbuzz(100) criterion reports 1.74µs for the original, 500ns for your version, and 800ns for just replacing the integer formatting.

Comment: (also swapping in [dtolnay's `itoa`](https://docs.rs/itoa/latest/itoa/index.html) brings it down to 450ns)

Comment: V8 also has the advantage that there is only one JavaScript thread, so the allocator doesn't have to consider that concurrent allocation attempts can happen.

Comment: @cdhowie: In this scenario, this is unlikely to make a difference. All modern allocators use a thread-local cache. For repeated allocations/deallocations the same memory block will be served from the thread-local cache over and over.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a large portion of the way to optimal by using `write!` instead of allocating a string for each number. This takes 75% of the time of the JavaScript version.

```rust
pub fn fizz_buzz2(n: u32) -> String {
    let mut res = String::with_capacity(calc_capacity(n as f32) as usize);
    res.push('1');

    for i in 2..n {
        res += " ";
        if i % 15 == 0 {
            res += "fizzbuzz";
        } else if i % 5 == 0 {
            res += "buzz";
        } else if i % 3 == 0 {
            res += "fizz";
        } else {
            use std::fmt::Write;
            write!(res, "{i}").unwrap();
        }
    }
    res
}
```

Then you can go further by not using the `write!` macro, since Rust doesn't prioritize speed for formatting. This takes 30% of the time of the JavaScript version, although technically it will break on some numbers that have the same number of digits as `u32::MAX`.

```rust
pub fn fizz_buzz3(n: u32) -> String {
    let mut res = String::with_capacity(calc_capacity(n as f32) as usize);
    let mut digits = '0'..='9';
    let digits: [char; 10] = std::array::from_fn(|_| digits.next().unwrap());
    res.push('1');

    for mut i in 2..n {
        res += " ";
        if i % 15 == 0 {
            res += "fizzbuzz";
        } else if i % 5 == 0 {
            res += "buzz";
        } else if i % 3 == 0 {
            res += "fizz";
        } else {
            let mut reverse = 0;
            let mut d = 0;
            while i > 0 {
                reverse *= 10;
                reverse += i % 10;
                i /= 10;
                d += 1;
            }
            for _ in 0..d {
                res.push(digits[(reverse % 10) as usize]);
                reverse /= 10;
            }
        }
    }
    res
}
```

Comment: For the last part: is [`itoa`](https://docs.rs/itoa/latest/itoa/index.html) faster, or not, than the hand-rolled code?

Comment: @MatthieuM. it's about the same speed.